# How do I get screened for (ovarian) cancer?

Tags: cancer, radiology

My wife faces infertility issues, and per a report on NBC news (http://www.nbcnews.com/health/cancer/can-infertility-point-ovarian-cancer-risk-n447901) she potentially faces a higher cancer risk for ovarian cancer.

How can my wife get appropriate screening\early diagnosis?  Does one typically begin by talking with a family doctor?

Comment: What does "fertility issues" mean in this context? Is it clear that it's your wife having them, has anything been diagnosed, has your wife seen a doctor about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests that can help detect ovarian cancer are pelvic exams, transvaginal ultrasounds, and some blood tests. [[1](http://www.cancer.gov/types/ovarian/patient/ovarian-screening-pdq)](http://www.cancer.gov/types/ovarian/patient/ovarian-screening-pdq) At least the first two are generally handled by gynecologist, and they are the specialists that know mist about ovarian cancer, so if possible, your wife should probably talk to one. If your wife doesn't have a gynecologist, a general practitioner (I assume that's what "family doctor" means) can at least refer her to one.

Please note that:

> There is no standard or routine screening test for ovarian, fallopian tube, and primary peritoneal cancer.

So these tests might not even detect it if it's there.

> Screening for ovarian cancer has not been proven to decrease the death rate from the disease.

Even if it's detected, it might not help.

Because you mention fertility problems, your wife might want to see a gynecologist anyway, though, who would perform a pelvic exam and a transvaginal ultrasound to check for a cause of the infertility anyway.

Comment: From your source, an important tidbit: "There is no standard or routine screening test for ovarian, fallopian tube, and primary peritoneal cancer.
Screening for ovarian cancer has not been proven to decrease the death rate from the disease."

Comment: @anongoodnurse yes, I read that. The question was still "what doctor to go to" and not "does screening make sense".. Gosh, the downvoting on this site is really out of control...

Comment: "How can my wife get appropriate screening\early diagnosis?" is also part of the question, and should (in my opinion) be in the answer. It has the potential to do some good. The DVs are no more out of control than the UVs, of which you've gotten many. Complaints about a rare DV are easy to dismiss.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone, its much appreciated (esp for such a sensitive subject).  @YviDe yes my wife has been diagnosed with fertility issues, PCOS and Endometriosis (all mentioned in the NBC article), and as a guy I've learned MUCH more about women's anatomy than I ever cared to =]  All interesting and helpful information however, thanks again for taking the time.